# Unable to cast object of type 'SubmitPO.VARCOMMERCE.PO.LineRequest[]' to type 'System.String[] using AddObject in RestSharp

Tags: vb.net, restsharp

When I try to create a RestSharp Request by adding an object I get this error: (It happens on **request.AddObject(po)**)

> Unable to cast object of type 'SubmitPO.VARCOMMERCE.PO.LineRequest[]' to type 'System.String[]

My code is like such:

'''

```
    Public Function submitPO(ByRef po As OrderRequestJson, ByVal test As Boolean) As IRestResponse

        'get bearer token
        Dim client = New RestClient("https://api.ingrammicro.com:443/sandbox/resellers/v6/orders")
        Dim request As RestRequest = New RestRequest() With {
            .Method = Method.POST
        }
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + Me.BearerAccessToken)
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        request.AddHeader("IM-CustomerNumber", Me.AccountNumber)
        request.AddHeader("IM-CountryCode", "US")
        request.AddHeader("IM-CorrelationID", Guid.NewGuid.ToString())
        request.AddObject(po)
        Dim response = client.Execute(request)

    End Function
```

'''

And the model is as such

'''
#Region "Request"

```
Public Class OrderRequestJson
    Public Property customerOrderNumber As String
    Public Property endCustomerOrderNumber As String
    Public Property notes As String
    Public Property acceptBackOrder As Boolean
    Public Property shipToInfo As Shiptoinfo
    Public Property lines As LineRequest()
    Public Property shipmentDetails As ShipmentDetails
    Public Property additionalAttributes As Additionalattribute()
End Class

Public Class Shiptoinfo
    Public Property contact As String
    Public Property companyName As String
    Public Property addressLine1 As String
    Public Property addressLine2 As String
    Public Property city As String
    Public Property state As String
    Public Property postalCode As String
    Public Property countryCode As String
    Public Property phoneNumber As String
    Public Property email As String
End Class

Public Class LineRequest
    Public Property customerLineNumber As String
    Public Property ingramPartNumber As String
    Public Property quantity As Integer
End Class

Public Class Additionalattribute
    Public Property attributeName As String
    Public Property attributeValue As String
End Class

Public Class ShipmentDetails
    Public Property carrierCode As String
    Public Property freightAccountNumber As String
    Public Property shipComplete As String
    Public Property requestedDeliveryDate As String
    Public Property signatureRequired As Boolean
    Public Property shippingInstructions As String
End Class
```

#End Region
'''

Comment: Reading the error, my feeling is the AddObject method is expecting a string.  Do you perhaps need to serialise to a json string your OrderRequestJson instance before attempting to submit it?

Comment: It's quite unclear what your API expects. You are submitting a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request, which needs a collection of key-value pairs. How do you expect your complex object properties to be represented as plain strings? `AddObject` only works with primitive types, or collections of primitive types.